# Repeat rows based on numbers in multiple columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I have a lot of data that I'm trying to do some basic machine learning on, kind of like the Titanic example that predicts whether a passenger survived or died (I learned this in an intro Python class) based on factors like their gender, age, fare class...

What I'm trying to predict is whether a screw fails depending on how it was made (referred to as Lot). The engineers just listed how many times a failure occurred. Here's how it's formatted.

| Lot | Failed? |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 110 | 0 |
| 120 | 1 |
| 130 | 4 |

The values in the cells are the number of occurrences, so for example:

Lot 100 had three screws that failed

Lot 110 had 0 screws that failed

Lot 120 had one screw that failed

Lot 130 had four screws that failed

I plan on doing a `logistic regression` using `scikit-learn`, but first I need each row to be listed as a failure or not. What I'd like to see is a row for every observation, and have them listed as either a `0` (did not occur) or `1` (did occur). Here's what it'd look like after

| Lot | Failed? |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 110 | 0 |
| 120 | 1 |
| 140 | 1 |
| 140 | 1 |
| 140 | 1 |
| 140 | 1 |

Here's what I've tried and what I've gotten

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Lot' : ['100', '110', '120', '130'],
'Failed?' : [3, 0, 1, 4]
}) 

df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Failed?'])].reset_index(drop = True)
```

When I do this it repeats the rows but keeps the same values in the `Failed?` column.

| Lot | Failed? |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 110 | 0 |
| 120 | 1 |
| 140 | 4 |
| 140 | 4 |
| 140 | 4 |
| 140 | 4 |

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think what you are trying is correct. B/c for predicting a real value you should be using linear regression.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to accept the best solution as answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. Thank you! Please see the following for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.Series.repeat` with `reindex`, but first you need to differentiate between rows that have `0` and those that do not:

```
s = df[df['Failed?'].eq(0)] # "save" rows with 0 as value as they will be excluded in repeat since they are repeated 0 times.
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Failed?'])) #repeat each row depending on value
df['Failed?'] = 1 #set all values equal to 1
df = pd.concat([df,s]).sort_index() #bring in the 0 values that we saved as 's' earlier and sort by the index to put back in order
df
```

---

```
#The above code as a one-liner:
(pd.concat([df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Failed?'])).assign(**{'Failed?' : 1}),
            df[df['Failed?'].eq(0)]])
   .sort_index())

Out[1]: 
   Lot  Failed?
0  100        1
0  100        1
0  100        1
1  110        0
2  120        1
3  130        1
3  130        1
3  130        1
3  130        1
```

Comment: nice solutoin! d

Answer (score 0):

below will give you failure or not but I suppose you are better served by the other answer.

```
df.loc[df['Failed?']>0,'Failed?'] = 1
```

Just as a comment: this is a bit of a strange data transformation, you might want to just keep a numerical target variable